# XSL Hyperlink with parameters

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm working on a menu and having some trouble with creating hyperlinks in my XSL.  What I want to do is get the value of ITEMNMBR from the xsl and when the link is clicked, redirect to that page, passing ITEMNMBR in the query string.

I laid out what I thought would work eventually but then realized that I don't know how to get value of ITEMNMBR used in the href value.

Has anyone done this and could help?  I'm a newbie to XML so this is a beginner question I'm sure.  If there is a better way to do this or if someone could point me to even a good tutorial, I'd very much appreciate it.

```
<xsl:for-each select="MenuItem">    <!-- 3rd level menu names --> 
  <li><a href="~/Pages/orders/OrderEntry.aspx?ITEMNMBR="><xsl:value-of select="ITEMNMBR"/></a></li>  <!-- Inventory items -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[attribute-value-templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)** in your attributes:

```
<xsl:for-each select="MenuItem">    <!-- 3rd level menu names --> 
  <li><a href="~/Pages/orders/OrderEntry.aspx?ITEMNMBR={ITEMNMBR}"><xsl:value-of select="ITEMNMBR"/></a></li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks very much, that did it.  So with capturing the value like that, could I also put a javascript call in there and pass that value to a function (say to handle special characters like ampersand, etc)?

Comment: Yep, I will do that.  It's making me wait 5 minutes for some reason.